# Paid internship in Spain

Tags: visa, working-visas, spain

I would like to ask about which type of visa I should apply for if I want to work as an intern in Spain, for over 6 months with salary.

I am not from the EU, but I am now studying in the UK (holding a tier 4 student visa).

In addition, what documents are needed for my application? I have checked the Spanish embassy website which mentions that a student visa only allows a student to work an unpaid internship, but there's nothing related to a paid internship.

Comment: Your prospective employer would probably need to sponsor you for a work permit.

Comment: Which nationality do you have?

Comment: As a general rule, a company can only employ a non-EU citizen for a job in the EU if they demonstrate that no EU citizen who fits the job description is available. With 50% unemployment among new graduates in Spain, that's not going to be easy for an internship.

Comment: It would be great if you share your experience here after a year. Thanks